# Override Interface MTU

Tags: mtu

I'm currently investigating an unusual MTU issue. I have a server running Red Hat with a single interface which has an MTU of 1500. I have verified this by running `netstat -i`. When I packet capture the interface, the MTU seems to be completely ignored and there are individual Ethernet frames larger than 1500 leaving the interface. I always thought that this was impossible because the OS ensured the frames were fragmented to the configured MTU. I've had a couple of CCIE engineers look at the capture and they have confirmed these are single frames (I'm not misreading the capture).

Has anyone got any idea what might be happening? Is it possible for a TCP connection to override the MTU? I know that it can set the MSS but I thought this can't increase the MTU. I've been reading about path MTU discovery in more depth, can this increase the MTU of the interface?

Comment: Have you tried to add MTU=1500 in configuration at relevant interface?

Comment: @Datagram.Network Yes, it is set

Comment: Does your server have Jumbo Frames enabled? Unfortunately, host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: Disabling Large Send Offload may fix that.

Comment: No it doesn't have Jumbo Frames enabled (and shouldn't). I'll ask on Server Fault - I wasn't sure if it was suitable for here but concluded it needed someone with in-depth network knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/core/enable_tcp_offloading
```